# Finding documents through regex in Mongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre

I have a document structure like this one.

```
> db.urls.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d79c7020ba271c80b78b6c"),
    "url" : "http://www.newstoday.com.bd?option=details&news_id=2368296&date=2014-01-27///",
    "priority" : 0.25,
    "date" : ISODate("2014-07-29T13:06:58.745Z"),
    "seen" : 1
}
```

To find some document using regex I used the following,

```
> db.urls.find({url: { $regex: 'http://www.newstoday.com.bd?option='} })
>
```

Which resulted empty. I need some help on the proper regex to use here.

Comment: what is the input and what wouldbe the output

Comment: @Dews you need to escape `?` and `.` ,so it would be `db.urls.find({url: { $regex: 'http://www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?option='} })` or `db.urls.find({url: { $regex: 'http://www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?option=\S+'} })`

Comment: Avinash tried, but it didn't work.
vks, the output should be the document above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?=.*?http:\/\/www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?.*)(.*)
```

This will give the document based on the url if that is what you are looking for.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wE3dU7/1

Comment: could you give me a pymongo expression for this?

Comment: can only provide you with the regex.gotno idea about mongo :(

Comment: okey, I tried **db.urls.find({url: { $regex: '(?=.*?http:\/\/www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?.*)(.*)'} })** but it's not working...!

Comment: $regex: 'acme.*corp', $options: 's'.Apply this as well .

Comment: (.*?http:\/\/www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?.*) try this with s option

Comment: db.urls.find({url: { $regex: '(.*?http:\/\/www\.newstoday\.com\.bd\?.*)', $options: 's'} }) tried this with no luck!

Comment: Turns out to be a problem of mongo database. Due to some inconsistent state of database, item with the following string was `hidden` from query.